# why scroll is not working till end in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll

Whenever I try to scroll, it auto scrolls back, behaving like it is the end of the list.

[image]

Here is the screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:move_me_delivery/components/search_field.dart';
import 'package:move_me_delivery/data/styles.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 32),
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                SearchTextField(

                  focus: _focusNode,
                  onCancel: (){
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }),
                SizedBox(height: 15,),

                ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    Text("Recent requests", style: AppTextStyles.header1,),
                    SizedBox(height: 15,),

                    ListView.separated(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                            child: Text("BBQ", style: AppTextStyles.body1,),
                          );
                        }, separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return Divider();
                    }, itemCount: 5),

                    SizedBox(height: 15,),
                    Text("Restaurants nearby", style: AppTextStyles.header1,),

                    ListView.separated(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                            child: Text("BBQ", style: AppTextStyles.body1,),
                          );
                        }, separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return Divider();
                    }, itemCount: 16),
                  ],
                ),




              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in this case, i prefer using `CustomScrollView`, if you wish i can answer a demo

Comment: As you have requested focus on `SearchTextField` in your `initState` method. It scrolls back to the top because it is trying to keep `SearchTextField` focused. 

To solve this issue, you should use `autoFocus` in your `TextFormField` instead of calling `_focusNode.requestFocus();` at start.